Override spacing for a child element in a SwiftUI HStack
I have a horizontal scroll user experience with a ScrollView and an HStack. I wanted to figure out a way to realize that the user has reached the end of the HStack.
To accomplish that, I used this solution (open to better solutions)
The functionality works as expected and I can realize when the user is at the end of the scrollview.
This is my code so far
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
            content
            endOfListView
        }
    }
}

private var endOfListView: some View {
    Color.clear
        .frame(width: .zero, height: .zero)
        .onAppear {
            didReachEnd = true
        }
}

The issue I am having now is that even the endOfListView has a frame of .zero, an additional 10 spacing is added because of the spacing set in the HStack constructor.
I tried to add this .padding(.leading, -10) to the endOfListView, however, that didn't help and the spacing was still there.
I also came across a similar problem but doesn't concern the spacing so I couldn't apply it.
Is there a way override the spacing for specific elements within an HStack or an alternative way to solve this ?

Have you tried moving endOfListView outside of the LazyHStack, so that it’s a direct child of the ScrollView?

Thank you @bdesham - works great. Happy to mark it as an answer if you answer it or happy to delete question if you feel it is too trivial.

If the LazyHStack is adding unwanted spacing before your sentinel view, just move the sentinel view out of it! You should be able to put your endOfListView marker directly within the ScrollView:
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
            content
        }
        endOfListView
    }

It still comes “after” all of the content in the LazyHStack, so it should still serve its purpose of allowing you to run some code when the user has reached the end.

While this does indeed solve my issue, it does create a bug in my logic.
I needed this view to be within my LazyHStack so that it is loaded lazily when we reach the end. Adding it to the scrollview fires the endOfListView's onAppear immediately.

Ah, okay. In that case I would set the spacing to zero for the LazyHStack, and implement the spacing manually by adding a Spacer between each of the “real” items, but not between the last item and the endOfListView.

Try putting your detector view in the background of the content instead:
LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
    content
        .background(alignment: .trailing) {
            endOfListView
        }
}


when I do this, my didReachEnd = true gets set to true immediately as the view appears on screen. I use this view to detect when I've scrolled to the end.

@ShawnFrank Assuming content contains a collection of sub-views, try moving the detector to the background of the last element inside content.

You are right, there is a collection. While that is an option, this code is inside a custom CarouselView. So I use it like CarouselView {  loop over collection } - I pass a binding to the CarouselView to notify me when we have reached the end. I was hoping the CarouselView could tell us when the end has reached rather than doing this work from the main view.

@ShawnFrank You said in the OP that negative trailing padding didn't work when it was applied to endOfListview. Try applying it to the ScrollView instead.

You can use View Extractor to extract the last view in content, put that view and endOfListView in their own HStack, with whatever spacing you like.
LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
    ExtractMulti(content) { views in
        ForEach(views) { view in
            // assuming the IDs are unique
            if view.id == views.last?.id {
                // suppose I want no spacing between the last view and endOfListView
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    view
                    endOfListView
                }
            } else {
                view
            }
        }
    }
}

